# How to show the find and replace panel with a pre-populated search string?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I know that it is possible to show the Sublime Text "Find and Replace" panel using the `show_panel` command (either via a keybinding or a plugin), and control which arguments are enabled/disabled.

Example run from Sublime Console panel:

```
window.run_command('show_panel', { 'panel': 'replace', 'regex': True, 'case_sensitive': False, 'whole_word': False, 'in_selection': False, 'wrap': True, 'highlight': True, 'preserve_case': True })
```

What I would like to know, is: is there a way to pre-populate the `Find What:` and `Replace With:` values?

I found [this forum post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/send-args-to-find-in-files-panel/5610/4) but it has no reply, and the [unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/commands.html) is of no help in this case.

I have tried:

- `'find_what': 'string'`
- `'replace_with': 'string'`
- `'find_history': 'string'`
- `'replace_history': 'string'`
- `'find_history': ['string']`
- `'replace_history': ['string']`
- `'find': 'string'`
- `'replace': 'string'`

EDIT: I have also tried:

- `characters`
- `find_characters`
- `look_for`
- `search_for`
- `find_regex`
- `find_string`
- `search_string`
- `replacement`
- `search_characters`

and none of the above makes any difference - the panel is always pre-populated with the previous search and replace values, not what I pass in.

---

I am aware of the commands `slurp_find_string` and `slurp_replace_string`, which will take the current selection and update the `Find What` / `Replace With` values respectively, but I would like a way to do it without having to mess around with selections first - I just want to pass the values as arguments directly to the `show_panel` command.

Does anyone know what parameters/arguments can be used to control this?

Comment: Silly question, but did you try `find_string` and `replace_string`?

Comment: Darn, it doesn't seem to be working for me: `window.run_command("show_panel", {"panel": "replace", "find_string": "foo", "replace_string": "baz"})` opens the panel, but doesn't populate the text boxes...

Answer (score 3):

You can run an insert command on the window just after you've run the `show_panel` command.

```
import sublime_plugin


class ShowPanelPrefilledCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, interactive=True):
        self.window.run_command('show_panel', {
            'panel': 'find_in_files',
            'where': '<open folders>',
            'whole_word': False,
            'case_sensitive': False,
            'preserve_case': False,
            'regex': False,
            'use_buffer': False,
            'show_context': False,
        })

        self.window.run_command('insert', {'characters': 'hello'})

        if not interactive:
            self.window.run_command('find_all', {'close_panel': True})
```

Comment: This plugin does insert "hello" in the `Find` field but it leaves the `Replace` field empty. To move the cursor to the `Replace` field, so a 2nd `insert` command could be run, I tried running `next_field` twice as a `sublime`, `window`, and `view` command via `run_command()` but all failed. Placing 2x `"command": "next_field"` in a sublime-macro and running that also failed, in hindsight I think `next_field` is for snippets only. I see no way around this unless there is a way to programmatically move the cursor between panel fields so the `Replace` field can be filled using an `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing for a key binding command that opens a Package Tool and uses the Find Search window.  I ended up with something easy to customize and use for any command that just uses another key binding.

After I run my Package Tool, I just use this key binding to insert the text (which is a complicated regex in my case).  For me on OSX, it's intuitively remembered as (insert 1) <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Open `Sublime Text / Preferences / Key Bindings`

Add this to the `User - Default (OS).sublime-keymap`

```
{ "keys": ["super+i", "super+1"], "command": "insert", "args": { "characters": "my-custom-insert-text1" } },
{ "keys": ["super+i", "super+2"], "command": "insert", "args": { "characters": "my-custom-insert-text2" } },

// etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added in Sublime Text build 4123 on 6 December 2021.

> The show_panel command for the find and find in files panels can now take "pattern" and "replace_pattern" arguments.